# How to assign local variable in Jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

Below, I am trying to print replaced items using Jquery template. There I want to set a variable **partHasBeenReplaced** which later I can use to print the label and close the `<span>` element.

1. How can I set variable there?
2. How to find the last element of type "REPLACEMENT"? it may not be the last element of the array.

   ```
               {{each(i,ref) productReferences}}
                       {{if ref.referenceType == 'REPLACEMENT'}}
                           {{partHasBeenReplaced = 'true'}}
                       {{/if}}
               {{/each}}

               {{if partHasBeenReplaced == 'true'}}
                   <span class="text-danger font-weight-bold pt-2">
                       This item has been replaced with:
               {{/if}}

               {{each(i,ref) productReferences}}
                       {{if ref.referenceType == 'REPLACEMENT'}}
                           {{= ref.target.code}} ,
                       {{/if}}
               {{/each}}

               {{if partHasBeenReplaced == 'true'}}
                   </span>
               {{/if}}
   ```

Comment: My usual approach is to sort/filter data beforehand, so the template contains as little logic as possible. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: I just want to know, is setting a local variable is at all possible?

Comment: I don't know, can you link us to the jquery templates library docs you're using? Judging from [this](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates), you can't.

Comment: yeah look like that only

Comment: otherway around is I can set productReferences from server, so here I just have to put if condition.

Answer (score 0):

In order to assign data to an element using such templates, it better to use attributes. We can access create/update/remove attribute using JavaScript.

For an example, if you want to add a data for `<span>` then you can do it using -

```
<span id="mySpan" class="text-danger font-weight-bold pt-2" partreplaced="{{partHasBeenReplaced}}" ></span>
```

It can be accessed in JavaScript using below method -

```
let span = document.querySelector("#mySpan");
let partreplaced = span.getAttribute('partreplaced');

console.log(partreplaced); //will print which was set in that attribute using the templating engine.
```

Comment: How would I set `{{partHasBeenReplaced}}` value? If I would able to set that variable then everything is sorted. it seems, setting a local variable in the template is not that easy as JSTL.

Comment: I think to that you have to add this syntax `"<c:out value='${partHasBeenReplaced}'/>"`

Comment: if you see my code, I am trying to create variable "partHasBeenReplaced" inside template so that I can use it. If it would have come from the server then it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple solution to set the local variable as we do in JSTL. So what I did is I have used JS to populate final flag like **partHasBeenReplaced** and set it to data before passing it to Jquery template. So that I can directly use the variable in the template.